# update CTE for multiple columns

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am deriving a CTE using data from 2 tables, and I have a requirement to update 2 columns in this CTE. The I can use UPADTE CTE and then a case statement to update one column, but the second one.

for example

```
update cte  
set col1 = case when thisrecord = thatrecord then 1 else 0 end 
    col2 = case max(thisrecord) = max(thatrecord) then 1 else 0 end
```

It gives me error.

If I use

```
update cte 
set col1, set col2 
from cte 
where this = that
```

then it says cte is not updatable as it has multiple base tables.

How to solve this puzzle, does anyone has a similar scenario or possible work out?

Comment: Are these two columns from the same table? If so - just use `UPDATE dbo.MyTable ....` and read the values from the CTE - update that base table instead of the CTE.

Comment: What I think @marc_s means, is that you can join the `UPDATE t FROM dbo.MyTable t JOIN CTE` to do what you need...

Comment: thank you guys...no these 2 cols are from 2 tables, values from these two tables are derived to one value(say x) based case searched expression andvalue X will be compared with another value Y. THis is a bit of requirement that the data to be changed before I take it to a new staging table. I can do it using a temp table and then editing it, but I want to avoid it. i am sharing the code

Comment: A single `UPDATE` statement *cannot* affect more than one table. Are `col1` and `col2` in the same table or different tables?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever; @marc_s . its 2 different tables

Comment: Then you need 2 separate `UPDATE` statements, and you can't share a CTE across multiple statements, so this approach is doomed to fail.

Comment: THen I guess it will be 2 different statements then. THank you all